# Igor Net_CDF loading error

Tags: netcdf, igor

I am trying to load in .nc files into Igor using the following line

```
 Execute/Q "Load_NetCDF/i/q/t/z/s"
```

I have the Load_NetCDF installed and have used it a lot - it definitely works and works for similar files. I think the difference is that these files contain a couple of multiple dimension waves. Using Load_NetCDF in this way seems to be producing some odd looking results which do not match the content if I look at the same file another way (i.e. looking at the variables individually in MATLAB's ncbrowser).

I am seeing a couple of errors in the Igor command line and have ensured that they occur on the Load_Netcdf line of my code as shown above. Here are the error messages I get:

I've been hunting around for help info on the Load_NetCDF external function but without success. Does anyone know the cause of this problem or a good line of attack to try debugging it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the XOP from [this page](http://www.ppl.eng.osaka-u.ac.jp/igor/) to load the netcdf data?
It states that it does not support 2D waves. I don't know any other XOP to load netcdf data.

The promised error messages in your post are not visible.

What netcdf files are these? Classic or the new format? The new format is based on HDF5 and can, according to [this post](http://www.igorexchange.com/node/1524#comment-2616) be read by the HDF5 browser in Igor.

Comment: I think they are new format, I'll check your post. The origin of this code has been somewhat mysterious to me as a collegue who has since left got me the software. +1 for the effort. :)